# How can I create redirect button with post method in Django template

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a button in the Django template which will redirect to another URL. But getting error 404 since Django can't recognize URL path rescribed in the urls.py.

HTML part

```
<form method="post" action='sts'>
{% csrf_token %}
 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="cts_link">cts</button>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rtRegRes.views import units
from rtRegRes.views import spartan

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^units/$', units),
    url(r'^units/sts/?$', spartan),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, render_to_response
from .models import rt_reg_res
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def units(request):
    """Return main webpage"""
    return render_to_response('runtime.html')

def spartan(request):
    """Link to the other unit webpages"""
    table = rt_reg_res.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qatables = request.POST.get("cts_link")
        if qatables:
            return render(request, 'cts.html', {'table': table})
```

Clicking the button following error message appears:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g36qK.jpg)

Could somebody point me what is wrong in my code

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rtRegRes.views import spartan , units

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^units/$', units),
    url(r'^units/sts/?$', spartan, name='sts'),
]
```

and

```
<form method="post" action='sts'>
{% csrf_token %}
 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="cts_link">cts</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the order of urls should help.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^units/sts/?$', spartan),
    url(r'^units/$', units),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that, but it's not helped... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What a pity, I wasted my time for nothing (( My code was correct, I just forget to rerun server after changes, every time reloaded page instead and did not see real changes. Anyway, thanks for the responses guys!!